# What unit should I use for HTML?

Tags: html, font-size, units-of-measurement

I like to use em, and tend to stay away from % because it tends to screw up the design easily, and pt, px, cm... Because they aren't that friendly to all devices. Am I right in doing so?

Comment: Recent on p.se: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25895/percentage-or-pixel-for-layouts

Comment: Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11803273/516188

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are reasons why css offers you a choice.  So it isn't really a question of right or wrong.  But if you are looking for a way to make your site more accessible by making fonts and elements scale easier, then you are on the right path.  Go with em.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Using em links dimensions to the font size and using % links to the size of the container (and ultimately the screen). In some places one will be better than the other for achieving a consistent effect. I agree it is generally good to avoid absolute units, but px is useful for small dimensions (e.g. border widths, shims).

Comment: One thing that continues to bug me about px/em is margin setting. So often I want fixed width margins but the rest of my layout will be fluid :/

Comment: @Danjah - There's nothing inherently wrong with px dimensions, just don't use them for things like column widths or text containers.

Comment: 49% column a, 49% column b, leaves 2% - but I want L/R margins at 10px not 1%, so I am left with a gap somewhere...

Comment: @Danjah - Don't over-constrain the widths then. Define the margins and allow the columns to expand to fill the space.

Comment: The thing is that I prefer having a design like the one on this very page, rather than any set percentage. With this design, if you want to focus on the right-hand menu, you can.

Comment: @DarkLightA - AFAICT this website has exact pixel widths for the main column (735px) and the sidebar (220px).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It scales, its easy to remember, and even easy to convert into other measurements for comparison :)