# Should I use px or rem value units in my CSS?

Tags: html, css, distance, units-of-measurement

I am designing a new website and I want it to be compatible with as much browsers and browser settings as possible. I am trying to decide what unit of measurement I should use for the sizes of my fonts and elements, but am unable to find a conclusive answer.

**My question is: should I use `px` or `rem` in my CSS?**

- So far I know that using `px` isn't compatible with users who adjust their base font size in their browser.
- I've disregarded `em`s because they are more of a hassle to maintain, compared to `rem`s, as they cascade.
- Some say that `rem`s are resolution independent and therefore more desirable. But others say that most modern browsers zoom all elements equally anyway, so using `px` is not a problem.

I'm asking this because there are a lot of different opinions as to what is the most desirable measure of distance in CSS, and I am not sure which is best.

Comment: This a matter of dispute and argumentation and opinion, not the kind of technical questions that SO is good at. By the way, the correct answer is “No.” ☺

Answer (score 584, accepted):

**TL;DR:** use `px`.

## The Facts

- First, it's extremely important to know that [per spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#x39), the CSS `px` unit **does not** equal one physical display pixel.  This has *always* been true – even in the 1996 [CSS 1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS1-20080411/#length-units).

  CSS defines the *reference pixel*, which measures the size of a pixel on a 96 dpi display.  On a display that has a dpi substantially different than 96dpi (like Retina displays), the user agent rescales the `px` unit so that its size matches that of a reference pixel.  In other words, this rescaling is exactly why 1 CSS pixel equals 2 physical Retina display pixels.

  That said, up until 2010 (and the mobile zoom situation notwithstanding), the `px` almost always did equal one physical pixel, because all widely available displays were around 96dpi.
- Sizes specified in `em`s are relative *to the parent element*.  This leads to the `em`'s "compounding problem" where nested elements get progressively larger or smaller.  For example:

  ```
    body { font-size:20px; } 
    div { font-size:0.5em; }
  ```

  Gives us:

  ```
    <body> - 20px
        <div> - 10px
            <div> - 5px
                <div> - 2.5px
                    <div> - 1.25px
  ```
- The CSS3 `rem`, which is always relative only to the root `html` element, is now supported on [99.67% of all browsers in use](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=rem).

## The Opinion

I think everyone agrees that it's good to design your pages to be accommodating to everyone, and to make consideration for the visually impaired.  One such consideration (but not the only one!) is allowing users to make the text of your site bigger, so that it's easier to read.

In the beginning, the only way to provide users a way to scale text size was by using relative size units (such as `em`s).  This is because the browser's font size menu simply changed the root font size.  Thus, if you specified font sizes in `px`, they wouldn't scale when changing the browser's font size option.

Modern browsers (and even the not-so-modern IE7) all changed the default scaling method to simply zooming in on everything, including images and box sizes.  Essentially, they make the reference pixel larger or smaller.

Yes, someone could still change their browser default stylesheet to tweak the default font size (the equivalent of the old-style font size option), but that's a very esoteric way of going about it and I'd wager nobody<sup>1</sup> does it.  (In Chrome, it's buried under the advanced settings, Web content, Font Sizes.  In IE9, it's even more hidden.  You have to press Alt, and go to View, Text Size.)  It's much easier to just select the Zoom option in the browser's main menu (or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd>/mouse wheel).

<sup>1 - within statistical error, naturally</sup>

If we assume most users scale pages using the zoom option, I find relative units mostly irrelevant.  It's much easier to develop your page when everything is specified in the same unit (images are all dealt with in pixels), and you don't have to worry about compounding.    (*"I was told there would be no math"* – there's dealing with having to calculate what 1.5em actually works out to.)

One other potential problem of using only relative units for font sizes is that user-resized fonts may break assumptions your layout makes.  For example, this might lead to text getting clipped or running too long.  If you use absolute units, you don't have to worry about unexpected font sizes from breaking your layout.

So my answer is use pixel units.  I use `px` for everything.  Of course, your situation may vary, and if you must support IE6 (may the gods of the RFCs have mercy on you), you'll have to use `em`s anyway.

Comment: You should use pixels and rem. So newer browsers get rem and old browsers fall back to pixels (like WordPress 2012 does). This can be automatted with Sass or Less so all you do is enter the px value and it automatically outputs px and rem.

Comment: My big quibble with this argument is that when adjusting font size and spacing at responsive breakpoints you can set a new font size on the html element and every measurement you've set in rem will automatically adjust, while with px you'll need to write new rules for every measurement you'd like to tweak. Of course more adjustments will probably be needed even when using rem, but with clever planning you get a huge amount of proportional scaling for free. Tying certain box spacing measurements to type, lighter code, and less complexity/ more maintainability equals a clear win for rem to me.

Comment: I don't understand in which case you need to do this
`div { font-size:0.5em; }`
it looks like very bad...
font-size should be given only to text tag... and you have to handle only for example:
`li { font-size:1.2em }
li li { font-size:1.em }`
in DIV tag you give percent value to font-size EXACTLY for scale texts of that DIV.... and with classes, not with "div"

Comment: Assuming that no user changes the font-size setting is quite bold. Such claim should be backed with data. Otherwise it just a way to alienate some of the users that are already fragile (heavily visually impaired ppl). If you can, use rem instead of px. IMO, apps should be able to scale independently their interface and the font-size. "Just use px" is what many devs struggling with ems issue want to hear, but it is not the right answer for the web.

Comment: i love this answer. pixels are just as arbitrary as any other unit, but they have the added benefit of being the same unit used in images / other computer media. in the future i think pixels will represent a reliable relative measurement for digital media and not whatever currently makes them semantically confusing.

Comment: Do you think this is still the case?

Comment: As far as `rem`s, that really depends on whether or not you still need to support [IE 8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem).  I still prefer px though.

Comment: Would be great to have a follow-up on this. Rem is now at 95%+ support.

Comment: I think this answer is correct for responsive sites where the layout is done in %

Comment: When using pixels, on mobile devices some things are ridiculously small. I ended up using centimeters. Of course, it's not accurate centimeters, but it did cause the buttons to be about the same size on computer and mobile phone.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 uses rem. So we are going to be forced to use that. There is choice but since bootstrap is mainstream we are going to be "forced" to use  rem.

Comment: From http://caniuse.com/#search=rem : `IE 9 & IE 10 do not support -**rem** units when used in the font shorthand property (the entire declaration is ignored) or when used on pseudo elements.` ...It all comes down to Windows - do you have users with Windows 7 ? Yes? Well you should support IE9, because many did update to IE9 but also many users did not update to 10/11. IE8 does not support `rem` but it is only hardly seen nowadays - under 1% of usage, some kind of support of `rem` is about 95% (2016-04-16 | YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: @GorillaApe One of the reasons why I am still using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 uses rem ... true, but today I see a significant difference in font size treatment with Firefox being significantly larger (to the point of almost breaking the site design). So test, check, and confirm before you jump to rem for fonts. Bootstrap 3 with pixel based fonts had no problem (maybe I've just hit browser/screen resolution type issues but I see similar problems in REM based sites today).

Comment: @RobBygrave - interesting. I mainly use Firefox (Dev Edition and Nightly), switching to Safari/Chrome/Edge/Opera for testing and never had this issue, neither with desktop nor the mobile version. Is it possible that it is your browser?

Comment: @cchiera You say to do something without saying why we should do it. That is extremely unconvincing, as if we should just do it because someone else said it's a good idea without actually understanding why. Why should we use pixels and rem, why not just pixels?

Comment: Couldn't agree more about the user set font size messing up the UI. I was the victim of the same recently. After reading some articles that advocate not setting a root font size and converting all my px values to rem, I delivered my project.

The default px assumption was for 16px, where my layout shines but my client had 10px set as his browser font which screwed my layout royally.

Comment: It's a lot easier to change the default font size since most (all?) browsers now allow searching for settings. So in Chrome I can go to settings, search "font", and the font settings appear.

I tried doing this and it's annoying because a lot of sites just use `px`, so I can't increase text size without zooming every damn part of the website.

Comment: While it is true that browser "zooming" technique changed over the years, having a relative font-size (like rem) is not about zooming per-se: it's about user style sheets and their effect. People with poor vision will sometimes set the text size to "Large" (or similar) via their browser settings. This sets the browser CSS stylesheet (_cascading_ stylesheets) to increase the text size where it can. If your website stylesheet constrains text size to a pixel value, then this accessiblity feature is denied to those users.

Answer (score 452):

<sub>I would like to praise [josh3736's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11803273/497418) for providing some excellent historical context. While it's well articulated, the CSS landscape has changed in the almost five years since this question was asked. When this question was asked, `px` *was* the correct answer, but that no longer holds true today.</sub>

---

**tl;dr:** use `rem`

### Unit Overview

Historically `px` units typically represented one device pixel. With devices having higher and higher pixel density this no longer holds for many devices, such as with Apple's Retina Display.

`rem` units represent the **r**oot **em** size. It's the `font-size` of whatever matches `:root`. In the case of HTML, it's the `<html>` element; for SVG, it's the `<svg>` element. The default `font-size` in every browser* is `16px`.

### On Using `px`

The majority of CSS examples on the internet use `px` values because they were the de-facto standard. `pt`, `in` and a variety of other units *could* have been used in theory, but they didn't handle small values well as you'd quickly need to resort to fractions, which were longer to type, and harder to reason about.

If you wanted a thin border, with `px` you could use `1px`, with `pt` you'd need to use `0.75pt` for consistent results, and that's just not very convenient.

### On Using `rem`

`rem`'s default value of `16px` isn't a very strong argument for its use. Writing `0.0625rem` is *worse* than writing `0.75pt`, so why would anyone use `rem`?

There are two parts to `rem`'s advantage over other units.

- User preferences are respected
- You can change the apparent `px` value of `rem` to whatever you'd like

#### Respecting User Preferences

Browser zoom has changed a lot over the years. Historically many browsers would only scale up `font-size`, but that changed pretty rapidly when websites realized that their beautiful pixel-perfect designs were breaking any time someone zoomed in or out. At this point, browsers scale the entire page, so font-based zooming is out of the picture.

Respecting a user's wishes is not out of the picture. Just because a browser is set to `16px` by default, doesn't mean any user can't change their preferences to `24px` or `32px` to correct for low vision or poor visibility (e.x. screen glare). If you base your units off of `rem`, any user at a higher font-size will see a proportionally larger site. Borders will be bigger, padding will be bigger, margins will be bigger, everything will scale up fluidly.

If you base your media queries on `rem`, you can also make sure that the site your users see fits their screen. A user with `font-size` set to `32px` on a `640px` wide browser, will effectively be seeing your site as shown to a user at `16px` on a `320px` wide browser. There's absolutely no loss for responsive web design (RWD) in using `rem`.

#### Changing Apparent `px` Value

Because `rem` is based on the `font-size` of the `:root` node, if you want to change what `1rem` represents, all you have to do is change the `font-size`:

```css
:root {
  font-size: 100px;
}
body {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<p>Don't ever actually do this, please</p>
```

***Whatever you do, don't set the `:root` element's `font-size` to a `px` value.***

If you set the `font-size` on `html` to a `px` value, you've blown away the user's preferences without a way to get them back.

If you want to change the *apparent* value of `rem`, use `%` units.

The math for this is reasonably straight-forward.

The apparent font-size of `:root` is `16px`, but lets say we want to change it to `20px`. All we need to do is multiply `16` by some value to get `20`.

Set up your equation:

```
16 * X = 20
```

And solve for `X`:

```
X = 20 / 16
X = 1.25
X = 125%
```

```css
:root {
  font-size: 125%;
}
```

```html
<p>If you're using the default font-size, I'm 20px tall.</p>
```

Doing everything in multiples of `20` isn't all that great, but a common suggestion is to make the apparent size of `rem` equal to `10px`. The magic number for that is `10/16` which is `0.625`, or `62.5%`.

```css
:root {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

```html
<p>If you're using the default font-size, I'm 10px tall.</p>
```

The problem now is that your default `font-size` for the rest of the page is set way too small, but there's a simple fix for that: Set a `font-size` on `body` using `rem`:

```css
:root {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

```html
<p>I'm the default font-size</p>
```

It's important to note, with this adjustment in place, the apparent value of `rem` is `10px` which means any value you might have written in `px` can be converted directly to `rem` by bumping a decimal place.

```
padding: 20px;
```

turns into

```
padding: 2rem;
```

The apparent font-size you choose is up to you, so if you want there's no reason you can't use:

```
:root {
  font-size: 6.25%;
}
body {
  font-size: 16rem;
}
```

and have `1rem` equal `1px`.

So there you have it, a simple solution to respect user wishes while also avoiding over-complicating your CSS.

### Wait, so what's the catch?

I was afraid you might ask that. As much as I'd like to pretend that `rem` is magic and solves-all-things, there are still some issues of note. Nothing deal-breaking **in my opinion**, but I'm going to call them out so you can't say I didn't warn you.

#### Media Queries (use `em`)

One of the first issues you'll run into with `rem` involves media queries. Consider the following code:

```
:root {
  font-size: 1000px;
}
@media (min-width: 1rem) {
  :root {
    font-size: 1px;
  }
}
```

Here the value of `rem` changes depending on whether the media-query applies, and the media query depends on the value of `rem`, so what on earth is going on?

`rem` in media queries uses the initial value of `font-size` and *should not* (see Safari section) take into account any changes that may have happened to the `font-size` of the `:root` element. In other words, it's apparent value is *always* `16px`.

This is a bit annoying, because it means that you have to do *some* fractional calculations, but I have found that most common media queries already use values that are multiples of 16.

```
|   px | rem |
+------+-----+
|  320 |  20 |
|  480 |  30 |
|  768 |  48 |
| 1024 |  64 |
| 1200 |  75 |
| 1600 | 100 |
```

Additionally if you're using a CSS preprocessor, you can use mixins or variables to manage your media queries, which will mask the issue entirely.

##### **Safari**

Unfortunately there's a known bug with Safari where changes to the `:root` font-size do actually change the calculated `rem` values for media query ranges. This can cause some very strange behavior if the font-size of the `:root` element is changed within a media query. Fortunately the fix is simple: [use `em` units for media queries](https://zellwk.com/blog/media-query-units/).

#### Context Switching

If you switch between projects various different projects, it's quite possible that the apparent font-size of `rem` will have different values. In one project, you might be using an apparent size of `10px` where in another project the apparent size might be `1px`. This can be confusing and cause issues.

My only recommendation here is to stick with `62.5%` to convert `rem` to an apparent size of `10px`, because that has been more common in my experience.

#### Shared CSS Libraries

If you're writing CSS that's going to be used on a site that you don't control, such as for an embedded widget, there's really no good way to know what apparent size `rem` will have. If that's the case, feel free to keep using `px`.

If you still want to use `rem` though, consider releasing a Sass or LESS version of the stylesheet with a variable to override the scaling for the apparent size of `rem`.

---

<sub>* I don't want to spook anyone away from using `rem`, but I haven't been able to officially confirm that *every* browser uses `16px` by default. You see, there are a lot of browsers and it wouldn't be all that hard for one browser to have diverged ever so slightly to, say `15px` or `18px`. In testing, however I have not seen a single example where a browser using default settings in a system using default settings had any value other than `16px`. If you find such an example, please share it with me.</sub>

Comment: I know this is late but, I like the way using REM, but I have most problem using rem is when I use `matrix()` with javascript which is matrix translate values are using  `px` (correct me if I am wrong), and I am so confused with it.

Comment: @Ampersanda, in JavaScript you're largely going to use computed pixel values. My recommendation is to toggle classes where possible so that CSS can manage how things look. For some things you won't be able to avoid using JS to compute pixel values, so your best bet there is to compute the pixel value from the DOM state.

Comment: I see, so I have to `getComputedStyle()` but the result is on always pixel, so I have to divide the result by the `rem` value (like 16). CMIIW

Comment: @Ampersanda only if you're actually generating a `rem` value, if you already have the correct `px` value, there's no need to switch to `rem` units for things that are already computed for the given context.

Comment: **have 1rem equal 1px** This causes troubles due to Chrome's minimum font-size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378664/rem-based-layouts-zooming-on-chrome-is-inconsistent-px-vs-rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200797/chrome-will-increase-the-font-size-when-zooming-out

Comment: To elaborate on @Paul, in order to both work around the Chromium bug *and* respect a user configured font size, use `font-size:100%` on the root element. Then use a calculator to figure out the body font size, once for every media query. Use css variables + calc() in order to set the other values once outside of the media queries (im assuming you design mobile first). I recommend to use the line-height (eg. font size * 1.5) as root unit and work with multiples of that. Because of the [vertical rhythm](https://zellwk.com/blog/why-vertical-rhythms/).

Comment: @Paul It actually doesn't. Chrome's min font-size applies only to **computed** font-sizes. Meaning that if you have a text element whose computed font-size is less than Chrome's min font-size, then Chrome will use its own min font-size. So, using this technique to be able to establish a 1:1 ratio between `rem` and `px` causes absolutely no problem, since no element on the page will "actually" go below Chrome's min font size. Not to mention that Chrome's min font-size is now 0px.

Comment: So your argument for why we should use rem is so that we can accommodate users who choose to use a nonstandard method of zooming browser content, and then in the same post you say that its ok that we don't accommodate the 2% of people who have browsers that only support `px`? The percent of people who use a zoomed in web page is small, and the proportion of those people who do zoom who also alter the root font size is tiny, likely much less than 2% of people. Makes no sense? You say we should accommodate an astronomically small proportion of people while also neglecting 2% of people to use rem

Comment: You even go on to list multiple issues that occur only when using rem, that never occur when using px. This is a convincing post of why you should *not* use rem if anything. There is genuinely not a single convincing reason to not use `px` in this entire post.

Comment: @ICW Good points, using rem as a convention seems to have become plain cargo-culting. The projects where I've seen that convention never did or intend to change base font size. "everything will scale fluidly" is wishful thinking for messy production code. The constant conversion of px into rem when getting specs from designers slows down developers if anything.

Comment: Worth noting is that Firefox/Gecko doesn't scale `px` values of border widths when font-size is changed but if you define border widths in `rem`, those will be scaled. In some cases this may affect which unit you want to use. Chrome/Blink always scales both, though.

Comment: @ICW There's nothing nonstandard about the browser's stylesheet, or a user changing browser settings to improve legibility. The feature has been there forever, and will probably be there forever. If you wish to ignore users who use a this feature in your design, at least call it "rare" and not "nonstandard".

Answer (score 59):

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20220731000819/https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) describes pretty well the pros and cons of `px`, `em`, and `rem`.

The author finally concludes that the best method is probably to use both `px` and `rem`, declaring `px` first for older browsers and redeclaring `rem` for newer browsers:

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; } 
body { font-size: 14px; font-size: 1.4rem; } /* =14px */
h1   { font-size: 24px; font-size: 2.4rem; } /* =24px */
```

Comment: Yeah, it's what got me interested in the rem in the first place. Two things I don't understand: he only advises it as a unit of measurement for fonts (not elements), and if I understand him correctly the only real reason to use (r)em is so IE users can resize the text?

Comment: @Samuel I believe so. If not for text resizing, I believe we would prefer to be using `px`. As for unit for elements, sticking to `px` would be better as you usually would want to size elements precisely.

Comment: But if you do that, any browser setting that redefines the base font-size would screw up your layout right? Why not rem's for everything?

Comment: There are 2 kinds of zooming. i) Full zooming, this zooms every single elements on your site proportionally, including `px`-defined elements. ii) Text zooming, this only increases the text sizes. For this, only the text sizes increase while element dimensions remain unchanged. `em` and `rem` addresses the issue of latter.

Comment: As many comments note [here](http://blog.typekit.com/2011/11/09/type-study-sizing-the-legible-letter/) that, the reason we needed to ditch `px` is to enable resizing. Now if we use `rem`, we still have to provide `px` fallback (in older browsers).

Essentially what it means is `px` resizing support is better than `rem`. Newer browsers support `px` resizing and for older browsers any way we are going to fallback on `px`.
Now based on light of this conclusion, I am very interested in knowing, why use `rem`?

If I may see the light at end of tunnel.

Comment: There is no guarantee that values like 62.5% = 10px.  It only holds true when the browser's default font size has been set to 16px.  While this is the default, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Anyone combing through all of the answers here, trying to understand the problem fully, should also read these articles: https://medium.com/@sascha.wolff/dont-use-rem-em-for-paddings-margins-and-more-94e19026b000
https://mindtheshift.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/r-i-p-rem-viva-css-reference-pixel/

A very important point IMO:

**"The user has two options to configure the browser for individual preferences... you steal one option by letting it look exactly like the other. If someone says they just want to have the text bigger and not everything else, they have a reason."**

Comment: `html { font-size: 62.5%; }` ? That's not a good thing.

Answer (score 42):

**Yes, REM and PX are relative** yet other answers have suggested to go for REM over PX, I would also like to back this up using an accessibility example.
When user sets different font-size on browser, REM automatically scale up and down elements like fonts, images etc on the webpage which is not the case with PX.

---

In the below gif left side text is set using font size REM unit while right side font is set by PX unit.

[image]

> As you can see that REM is scaling up/down automatically when I resize
> the default font-size of webpage.(bottom-right side)

***Default font-size of a webpage is 16px which is equal to 1 rem (only for default html page i.e. `html{font-size:100%}`), so, 1.25rem is equal to 20px.***

P.S: who else is using REM? CSS Frameworks! like Bootstrap 4, Bulma CSS etc, so better get along with it.

Comment: Your scaling html's font-size attribute which everything thats em/rem is relative to but not pixels.Try zooming the browser +/-  which is what any sort of accessibility use case would do. The font DOES get bigger and smaller. Hacking font-size: % is not at all correlated to accessibility in a modern browser.

Comment: Sorry my dear @JohnCulviner. If you want to bug your vision impaired users time and again, having to pinch-to-zoom in or keystroke each of your websites when browsing, you're right. But the font size setting in the browser is one of the most used accessibility features and it takes exactly that burden from such users and simplifies their life.

Comment: EDIT - Volker is right about browser/OS font size setting. this above example doesn't show this though so is techincally incorrect. REM is the way to go for that although it unfortunately makes dev a bit harder!

Answer (score 11):

josh3736's answer is a good one, but to provide a counterpoint 3 years later:

I recommend using `rem` units for fonts, if only because it makes it easier for *you*, the developer, to change sizes. It's true that users very rarely change the default font size in their browsers, and that modern browser zoom will scale up `px` units. But what if your boss comes to you and says "don't enlarge the images or icons, but make all the fonts bigger". It's much easier to just change the root font size and let all the other fonts scale relative to that, then to change `px` sizes in dozens or hundreds of css rules.

I think it still makes sense to use `px` units for some images, or for certain layout elements that should always be the same size regardless of the scale of the design.

Caniuse.com may have said that only 75% of browsers when josh3736 posted his answer in 2012, but [as of March 27 they claim 93.78% support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem). Only IE8 doesn't support it among the browsers they track.

Comment: `Only IE8 doesn't support it among the browsers they track.` Huh? The linked page states that *“IE9 & IE10 don´t support rem units when used in font shorthand property or when used on pseudo elements. IE9, 10 & 11 don´t support rem units when used in line-height property when used on :before and :after pseudo elements. Borders sized in rem disappear when page is zoomed out in Chrome. Doesn´t work on Samsung Note II Android 4.3 browser & Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 on Android 4.2. Chrome 31-34 & Chrome-based Android (like 4.4) have font size bug occurring when root element has percentage-based size.”*

Comment: Also, related to your `as of March 27 they claim 93.78% support.` At the time of writing this comment, *caniuse* shows merely 91.79% full browser support. Looking at your percentage, I´m pretty sure you included the *buggy* browser support too (currently at 2.8%, which could be interpreted as an optimistic 94.6% overall coverage – but fact is that those 2.8% come with buggy, incomplete or even completely failing support… as noted in my previous comment: each bug being the result of different browser version and operating system combinations.) You might want to correct your answer accordingly…

Comment: A **deal-breaking** (imo) point from [this article](https://medium.com/@sascha.wolff/dont-use-rem-em-for-paddings-margins-and-more-94e19026b000): 

_The user has two options to configure the browser for individual preferences... you steal one option by letting it look exactly like the other. If someone says they just want the text bigger and not everything else, they have a reason._

As designers, we're tempted to use all-REM so everything looks good regardless of user's text size. But if we do that, the two options (zoom level and text size) basically become the same, removing control

Answer (score 9):

As a reflex answer, I would recommend using rem, because it allows you to change the "zoom level" of the whole document at once, if necessary. In some cases, when you want the size to be relative to the parent element, then use em.

*But* rem support is spotty, IE8 needs a polyfill, and Webkit is exhibiting a bug. Moreover, sub-pixel calculation can cause things such as one pixel lines to sometimes disappear. The remedy is to code in pixels for such very small elements. That introduces even more complexity.

So, overall, ask yourself whether it's worth it - how important and likely it is that you change the "zoom level" of the whole document within CSS?

For some cases it's yes, for some cases it'll be no.

So, it depends on your needs, and you have to weight pros and cons, because using rem and em introduces some additional considerations in comparison to the "normal" pixel-based workflow.

Keep in mind that it's easy to switch (or rather convert) your CSS from px to rem (JavaScript is another story), because the following two blocks of CSS code would produce the same result:

```
html {
}

body {
  font-size:14px;
}

.someElement {
  width: 12px;
}
```

---

```
html {
  font-size:1px;
}

body {
  font-size:14rem;
}

.someElement {
  width: 12rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the best way to program the font sizes of a website are to define a base font size for the `body` and then use em's (or rem's) for every other `font-size` I declare after that.  That's personal preference I suppose, but it's served me well and also made it very easy to incorporate a more [responsive design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/).

As far as using rem units go, I think it's good to find a balance between being progressive in your code, but to also offer support for older browsers.  [Check out this link about browser support for rem units](http://css3clickchart.com/#rem-units), that should help out a good amount on your decision.

Comment: Ok. But responsive design is just as easily done with px units right (just write your media queries based on px instead of em)?

Comment: You can, however, if you want to make your font-size smaller as your website's viewport width becomes smaller then you can change the `body` font-size and everything changes with it.

Comment: I'm not really worried about browser support. I'll just include a fallback px size for all sizes, so that older browsers have something to interpret.

Comment: Then go for the progressive way by using rem's.  As long as you provide a fallback, then I see no harm.  To me though it just seems like extra work, but perhaps not in your situation.

Answer (score 2):

`pt` is similar to `rem`, in that it's relatively fixed, but almost always DPI-independent, even when non-compliant browsers treat `px` in a device-dependent fashion.  `rem` varies with the font size of the root element, but you can use something like Sass/Compass to do this automatically with `pt`.

If you had this:

```
html {
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

then `1rem` would always be `12pt`.  `rem` and `em` are only as device-independent as the elements on which they rely; some browsers don't behave according to spec, and treat `px` literally.  Even in the old days of the Web, 1 point was consistently regarded as 1/72 inch--that is, there are 72 points in an inch.

If you have an old, non-compliant browser, and you have:

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

then `1rem` is going to be device-dependent.  For elements that would inherit from `html` by default, `1em` would also be device-dependent.  `12pt` would be the *hopefully* guaranteed device-independent equivalent: `16px / 96px * 72pt = 12pt`, where `96px = 72pt = 1in`.

It can get pretty complicated to do the math if you want to stick to specific units.  For example, `.75em of html = .75rem = 9pt`, and `.66em of .75em of html = .5rem = 6pt`.  A good rule of thumb:

- **Use `pt` for absolute sizes.**  If you really need this to be dynamic relative to the root element, you're asking too much of CSS; you need a language that compiles to CSS, like Sass/SCSS.
- **Use `em` for relative sizes.** It's pretty handy to be able to say, "I want the margin on the left to be about the maximum width of a letter," or, "Make this element's text just a bit bigger than its surroundings."  `<h1>` is a good element on which to use a font size in ems, since it might appear in various places, but should always be bigger than nearby text.  This way, you don't have to have a separate font size for every class that's applied to `h1`: the font size will adapt automatically.
- **Use `px` for very tiny sizes.**  At very small sizes, `pt` can get blurry in some browsers at 96 DPI, since `pt` and `px` don't quite line up.  If you just want to create a thin, one-pixel border, say so.  If you have a high-DPI display, this won't be obvious to you during testing, so be sure to test on a generic 96-DPI display at some point.
- **Don't deal in subpixels to make things fancy on high-DPI displays.** Some browsers might support it--particularly on high-DPI displays--but it's a no-no.  Most users prefer big and clear, though the web has taught us developers otherwise.  If you want to add extended detail for your users with state-of-the-art screens, you can use vector graphics (read: SVG), which you should be doing anyway.

Comment: pt is for printed media and never should be used for screens

Comment: @s-f CSS defines pt and px such that they're always the same ratio, despite this not being technically accurate usage of those terms (72pt = 96px = 1in).  In fact, in CSS, px isn't really a single device pixel.  On my screen, 1px is 2 device pixels.  The advantage of using pt over px is that you can easily specify element sizes relative to text-related sizes.

Answer (score -1):

Half (but only half) snarky answer (the other half is bitter disdain of the reality of bureaucracy):

Use vh

Everything is always sized to browser window.

Always allow scroll down, but disable horizontal scroll.

Set body width to be a static 50vh, and never code css that floats or breaks out of the parent div. (If they try to mock up something that looks like it does, clever use of a background gif can throw them off track.) And style only using tables so everything is held rigidly into place as expected. Include a javascript function to undo any ctrl+/- activity the user may do.

Users will hate you, because the site doesn't flow differently based on what they're using (such as text being too small to read on phones). Your coworkers will hate you because nobody in their right mind does this and it will likely break *their* work (though not yours). Your programming professors will hate you because this is not a good idea. Your UX designer will hate you because it will reveal the corners they cut in designing UX mock-ups that they have to do in order to meet deadlines.

Nearly everyone will hate you, except the people who tell you to make things match the mock-up and to do so quickly. Those people, however (which generally include the project managers), will be ecstatic by your accuracy and fast turn around time. And everyone knows their opinion is the only one that matters to your paycheck.

Comment: Hahahaha. Probably the most interesting answer I've read on SO. And, actually, it is not totally wrong. I wouldn't recommend vh for websites, but there are some domain-specific problems that require the whole page to be styled in vh (or even vw) units. Think of overlays for video and such. It is quite fascinating to see the whole page scale proportionally with window size. See also [fluid typography](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/fluid-typography/), and the article even mentions [vertical rhythm](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/).

Comment: Fair enough! I've personally only done this once, and only because I kept being complained to about things not perfectly matching mockup (never got that complaint again, afterwards. The UX people then made it a point to intercede with the project manager to point out that *some* deviation was okay to meet technical requirements.)

I'm honestly amused and surprised to have you point out to me that there's actually a useful scenario for that kind of design.

Answer (score -3):

Yes. Or, rather, no.

Er, I mean, it doesn't matter. Use the one that makes sense for your particular project. PX and EM or both equally valid but will behave a bit different depending on your overall page's CSS architecture.

UPDATE:

To clarify, I'm stating that usually it likely doesn't matter which you use. At times, you may specifically want to choose one over the other. EMs are nice if you can start from scratch and want to use a base font size and make everything relative to that.

PXs are often needed when you're retrofitting a redesign onto an existing code base and need the specificity of px to prevent bad nesting issues.

Comment: So your answer is that it doesn't matter? Or are there certain situations in which you would value one over the other? And if so, in what situations would this be the case?

Comment: @Samuel yes, there may be times you want to use one or the other. I've updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit confused with the original wording. It think you had REM in the title and EM in the body. It appears you are specifically asking about REM. The answer is still pretty much the same, but REM does have some additional benefits to consider but is mainly used the same as EM--it allows you to use a 'base' font size.

Comment: Why are "*em's [...] nice if you can start from scratch and want to use a base font size and make everything relative to that.*"? What is the advantage of (r)em's over px? Is it so IE users can resize the text, or are there other advantages over px (which seems to be more simple)?

Comment: EM and REM have the same benefit: you can set the HTML or BODY to a specific font size (say 10px) and then have everything else set as an EM or REM. That way, if you want to make all the type proportionally bigger, you just change that one initial 10px style to 11px. This was way more useful 5 years ago when we were all building our own custom JS based font resizing widgets. These days, browsers do such a better job at zooming (especially mobile) that I find it much less of a benefit. If you find PX simpler, then that's a benefit for you and certainly a valid reason to go with PX.

Comment: Ok, so other than accessibility issues for (older versions of) IE and proportional resizing, the (r)em has no advantages over a px-based design?

Comment: The benefits are all context-centric and really only apply to the developer. An end-user likely doesn't care at all what unit of measurement you are using to set the fonts at. My vote is to use what makes sense to you and don't over-think it.

Comment: Although this is one of the most poorly written answers I've ever seen on stackoverflow, I am inclined to agree that "it doesn't matter" is in fact the most accurate answer to this question.