# Is it OK to use rem for mobile website design

Tags: css, typography, mobile-browser

I am wondering if it is a good idea to use rem in my mobile website. Doing so makes life a lot easier but I don't have any older devices to test on and I can't find any clear information on support in ie mobile.

Comment: Related: [Should I use px or rem in my css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799236/should-i-use-px-or-rem-in-my-css)

Comment: http://caniuse.com/rem

Comment: I saw this table, but it does not specifically mention ie mobile. I know they are supposed to be compatible with the desktop version but experience with other mobile browsers makes me very pessimistic about compatibility claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 has the new “rem” unit which picks up the root (html) fontsize....IE7 and 8 don't support it but does it matter? **no**, since you mention Mobile and therefore rem should be fine. but you want to check for testing different mobile os/versions? Try this:

http://ahedg.es/w/rem.html

From the looks of it really old mobile OS and old ie dont support it