# Why is font-size unreliable when universally applied?

Tags: css, font-size

With the following CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:"Segoe UI";
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
.red {
    color: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
    font-size: 3em;
}
.orange {
    color: hsl(30, 100%, 50%);
    font-size: 3em;
}
.yellow {
    color: hsl(60, 100%, 50%);
    font-size: 3em;
}
.green {
    color: hsl(120, 100%, 50%);
    font-size: 3em;
}
.blue {
    color: hsl(210, 100%, 50%);
    font-size: 3em;
}
.indigo {
    color: hsl(230, 100%, 50%);
    font-size: 3em;
}
.violet {
    color: hsl(274, 100%, 50%);
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

...the attributes in the * selector work fine - they apply to all of the classes; however, if I move font-size there, the text grows to tyrannosauric proportions. You can see this by moving the font-size from the individual classes to the * class here: http://jsfiddle.net/NvTvr/8/

Why does this happen?

### UPDATE

So this is the way to go, then:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:"Segoe UI";
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 48px;
}
.red {
    color: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
}
```

...etc. (no font-size specified within the color classes); as seen in http://jsfiddle.net/NvTvr/10/

Comment: You should not have to apply any font styles to `*`. While not as problematic as `font-size`, you're still unnecessarily applying them to all elements as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to contain an answer. Edit the question only to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @BoltClock: Isn't it accepted practice to reset margin and padding to 0 via the * selector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `em` is relative to the context.

As `font-size` is inherited from the context, each descendant element with `em` `font-size` will multiply the current `font-size` up to the element that contains text content.

Let's see in practice, assuming:

```
* { font-size: 3em }
```

You're applying that (relative to context) `font-size` to **all** elements.

That means, the `html` element will have 3 times the default browser font-size. The `body` will have 3 times font-size of its container (`html`) which corresponds to 9 times the default font-size. And so forth for each element's ancestors.

There's a new unit that does not have this issue, `rem` which is relative to root. But this is not as widely supported (no IE<=8 support).

---

Going a bit off-topic for the `em` x `px` x `rem` debate in this section of the answer.

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/609561/1331430):

> Use `em` when you specifically want the size of something to depend on the current font size.

Modern browsers can scale `px` units just fine. `em` was used mostly when old IE was predominant and didn't scale the `px` font-size when zooming.

Still, `em` has it uses in web design. Say, when making CSS-icons that should scale relatively to the font-size of the text. But for overall layout, I go with `rem`/`px` which do not generate compound issues and headaches, or percentages when making fluid layouts.

The issue with `px` for font-size is that, if you ever need to change the overall size of the page's text, you will have to change every single `font-size` declaration that uses `px`. That's where `rem` comes to aid.

There's always an heated discussion about which unit to use for the `font-size`. Go with the one that gives less headaches and suffices for your project.

So in sum, it depends on personal preference and project requirements.

---

### *References:*

#### Definitions and explanations

- [CSS Length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) - MDN
- [Why em instead of px?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/609517/1331430) - SO question
- [Font sizing with rem](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) - Snook.ca

#### More discussions

- [Should I use px or rem in my css?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11799236/1331430) - SO question (recommends `px` for `font-size`)
- [Why Ems?](http://css-tricks.com/why-ems/) - CSS-Tricks (recommends `em` for `font-size`)

Comment: What do you mean by "it suffers cascading"?

Comment: @BoltClock is my wording incorrect? It is supposed to mean the effect described in the first section - the font-size set on an element cascades to descendants elements (maybe "is inherited" would make more sense here). Then this inherited font-size is compounded with the element's own `em` font-size. If you can improve the wording, please feel free to (little too sleepy atm but I may review this answer tomorrow if necessary).

Comment: @BoltClock I've removed that ambiguous part and added one more paragraph in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you use the **"*" selector you are applying font-size:3em to the parents of ".red",".green" etc**, (in this case the body ) as well; **em is a compounding unit** so with the way you are declaring font size you are applying font-size:3em to body (48px assuming 16px browser default) and then font-size:3em to your classes which means the font size will be 144px.

hope my explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The `em` unit, when using in the value of the `font-size` property, denotes the font size of the parent element. So declaring `* { font-size: 3em }` makes the font size of each element three times the font size of its parent element.

If you want to use a font size that is three times the browser’s default font size (which can be anything), then the simplest way is to declare `body { font-size: 3em }` and not declare `font-size` for other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jukka's explicit and implied* suggestions, the CSS is now:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*font-family: Consolas;*/
    /*font-family: Candara;/*
    /*font-family: Calibri;*/
    font-family:"Segoe UI";
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
body { font-size: 3em }
.red { color: hsl(0, 100%, 50%); }
.orange { color: hsl(30, 100%, 50%); }
.yellow { color: hsl(60, 100%, 50%); }
.green { color: hsl(120, 100%, 50%); }
.blue { color: hsl(210, 100%, 50%); }
.indigo { color: hsl(230, 100%, 50%); }
.violet { color: hsl(274, 100%, 50%); }
```

Update jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/NvTvr/11/

- Although, if you select TidyUp in jsfiddle, it vertically expands the one-line class and element declarations (I like the idea of keeping it all on one line if only one attribute is being set).