# Inconsistent font size rendering issue on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I am having an css issue on my site. The font size is not consistent across all pages. The difference is one version of bigger font size and one version of a regular small font size. The small font size is the one I prefer. **If the page is showing the content in big font, it will change it back to a smaller one after reload the page for a couple of times, it also changes back to the smaller one right away if you right click and select inspect element.** Thus, I am not sure how can I ping point the issue.
Here are the screenshots, one with the big font and one with the small font, and again the small font is the one I prefer.
[image: the big font]

[image: the small font]

Comment: did you test it in chrome?

Comment: yes, i was using chrome.

Comment: By default in the 1st run it is showing your desired font i.e. the 2nd one.
Cant spot the problem.

Comment: I know browsers print fonts different ways, but your case is so extreme it looks like you have zoom set in your browser. Perhaps thats the problem.

Comment: @Havenard, Your presumption is also part of what I thought. But the size of: `CRUD: create, read, update and delete in sqlite with Java` is fixed(same) in both. Hence the `zoom` issue is not valid here.

Comment: It seems like it's only happening on chrome, haven't see the same on firefox....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`body { font-size: 1.6rem;}` might be your issue... you can axe that from your style.css and it should be more consistent. It looks like chrome might not like rem on the body as can be seen in the linked question

removing/changing the bad line from the following class definition in style.css should fix you up

```
body, button, input, select, textarea {
   color: #404040;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-size: 1.6rem;
   line-height: 1.5;
}
```

[Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099844/chrome-not-respecting-rem-font-size-on-body-tag)

Text + good links from answer on other question:

"This seems to be a Chrome bug;  see [Issue 319623: Rendering issue when using % + REMs in CSS](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=319623), and/or a partly-merged duplicate: [Issue 320754: font-size does not inherit if html has a font-size in percentage, and body in rem](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=320754)"

Comment: it seems this is only happening on chrome though...

Comment: might be a chrome bug.. see linked issue