# Why does my website look distorted when loaded on Chrome, but works fine on all other browsers?

Tags: python, html, css, flask, caching

My Python Flask Website looks distorted when I load it on Chrome, but looks fine on all other browsers (Safari, Firefox etc.). I tried clearing the cache on Chrome but still looked the same after several attempts. I'm pretty sure that all of my code works since everything works fine on other browsers - do I need to reinstall Chrome?

(When I say distorted I mean the web page just doesn't look how it's supposed to look - different from how it looks on Safari and Firefox).

**Overview:**

[image: A picture of how my website looks on Chrome]

Comment: have you checked so it's not zoomed in?

Comment: Usually Chrome shows a magnify icon when the resolution is zoomed in or zoomed out, so it shouldn't be the problem

Answer (score 3):

I've had issues previously with font-size when testing responsiveness on chrome, I'm not sure if this will help your case as I'm not sure what you mean when you say the website looks distorted.

The issue was caused by chrome's user font size preference that can be changed in the settings. Although I didn't touch the setting, it seemed like it was somehow affecting how my font size was rendered. It might be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845183/inconsistent-font-size-rendering-issue-on-chrome). Update chrome to see if it still persists and try on other chromium based browsers.
You can also try changing the font size preference then changing it back, it worked for me until I restart chrome.