# Google Chrome resizing font on refresh

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm currently having a very annoying issue on Google Chrome whereby a site I am currently developing has the font size changing when I hit the f5 button.

When I enter the URL in the address bar it and press enter the correct font size is displayed. The size is also fine in all other browsers however if I press F5 once the page has loaded in chrome the page refreshes and the font size is much larger. If I open the dev tools no CSS rules etc have changed (of course) and selecting/deselecting a rule immediately resolves the issue.

Does anybody have any ideas why it would suddenly decide to do this?

Comment: what unit of font size are you using ,px,pt,em like that ?

Comment: I am using rem -

html{ font-size:62.5%}
body{font-size:1.8rem;}

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099844/chrome-not-respecting-rem-font-size-on-body-tag

Comment: do you have font-size defined in body tag like this body { font-size: 1.5 rem } ?

Comment: Do you have a @font-face in use? And can you explain why you would have `html{ font-size:62.5%} body{font-size:1.8rem;}`?? That sounds like a very convoluted and confusing way to write `html{font-size:112.5%}`

Comment: Speaking of confusing, maybe you did confuse Chrome with this construct. Maybe it's easier to just write `html{font-size:112.5%}` like I said. A quick and dirty test shows that Chrome does behave like you say with your CSS, but it behaves normally with mine.

Comment: it is fine now. I sorted it as per the link from Karthick. Thanks all!

Comment: OK, but can you at least explain why you are setting the html to 62.5% of the user's preferred size?

Comment: @MrLister It's a fairly common technique to allow for easier calculation of rems and ems in stylesheets later. Set the html's font size to 62.5%, and from that point on you can be safe in the knowledge that 1rem ~= 10px, 1.6rem ~= 16px etc.

Comment: @niaccurshi Not true. If you set the html to 62.5%, you cannot be safe that 1rem = 10px, because the user's preferred size may not be 16px. For instance, in my browser, the default is 15px, so 62.5% would be around 9px. However, if you set the html size to `10px`, then you can be sure that 1rem = 10px, because 10px = 10px! So just set `html {font-size:10px}` if you want 1rem to be 10px.

Comment: @MrLister The point is that it is easier for your calculations as a developer. If the user scales their own fonts then that matters little if you're styling your content correctly and with good relation to other sizing. The default font size for most people is 16px, I imagine that those developers who use browsers at 14px or 20px default font sizes may use different multipliers other than 62.5%.

Comment: To address separately your "set it to 10px" point, that would be counter intuitive to being respectful to the user's wishes. If you set a font size to 10px you are trying to force the user into a set font size, and this may be too small for their accessibility needs. In fact some people set their minimum font size to larger values to stop that very practice, and the way those who usually style font sizes to absolute pixel values style the rest of their content usually means that the experience is then broken for those requiring larger font sizes on screen.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. 62.5% doesn't make your calculations easier. If you want to respect the user's preferences, you force yourself to use 1.6rem for all normal texts to make them standard, so why change the font size at all? Why not leave the root font size as it is, and only use things like 1.5rem if you want to make a line 1.5 times as large? Then it won't matter what size the user has as a pref. Also. suppose that the user has 12px for a minimum font size. Then if you set the root size to 10px, 1rem will be 12px; are you absolutely sure that 2rem will come out as 20px rather than 24?

Comment: @MrLister, How you number your font sizes is inconsequential to anyone but you and your team. If you want to use 1.5rem to solely mean 50% bigger than the body font default then that's fine. However I work in teams where font sizes are all relative to those used in designs where we have an agreed default font size in browsers. In this situation it is, IMO, easier to scan rem values and know that 0.16rem (in the case of how we use it) is equivalent to our 16px in design. We don't have to get the calculators out, we just use numbers like for like :)

Comment: @MrLister, if the user has their default font size set to 20px rather than 16px it doesn't matter to us, because the relativity of font sizes is baked in through that initial body font %. 0.16rem means 16px to us, but it means 20px for the user. We don't need to know this, only that our styling is proportionate. So to answer your last question, we don't set font size to 62.5%, we set it to 625%. This avoids the issue of minimum font sizes, so we can be sure with what we're getting

Comment: @niaccurshi While that is a clever way of getting around the minimum font size, it doesn't appear to make the calculations any easier; you'll always have to write 0.16em if you want the "normal" size text, 0.24em for 50% bigger etc. And it doesn't address my remark that if you want, say, 25 pixels, you can just write 25px rather than doing some complicated math on the root font size. You hadn't mentioned the 625% trick before, BTW.

Comment: No I hadn't mentioned the 625% trick, I was talking more abstract but see we are being a bit more "practical" in what we're talking about here. The calculations are easy from a "meeting the design" point of view because you don't need to calculate anything. If you want 25px you use 0.25rem. If you want 301px you use 3.01rem. etc. etc. As I've said, this isn't to guarantee 25px for the user, but to guarantee you're using the designed font sizes while keeping relativity for the user's minimum font-size preference. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use

`html {
font-size: 10px;
}`

instead of percentage. Everything else can remain the same, this should solve it.