# Font Size Changing with Refresh

Tags: css, html, fonts, less, font-size

When I initially load my website the font sizes are all normal, but when I hit refresh the size almost doubles, and does not go back to normal.  I've checked changing the font size using Ctrl+ and Ctrl-  That changes the font back to a normal size (90% or 110% of the default size).

Everything validates.

http://mylivingspacefinder.com/

**======Added from author's comment======**

Here's the text-size rules:

```
h1 {
    .fontSize(10);
}

h2 {
    .fontSize(4);
}

body {
    .fontSize(2);
}

.fontSize(@sizeValue) {
  @remValue: @sizeValue;
  @pxValue: (@sizeValue * 10);
  font-size: ~"@{pxValue}px"; 
  font-size: ~"@{remValue}rem";
}
```

Comment: PLease post the relevent less, css and browser type

Comment: Here's the text-size rules:
`h1 {
 .fontSize(10);
}

h2 {
 .fontSize(4);
}

body {
 .fontSize(2);
}

.fontSize(@sizeValue) {
  @remValue: @sizeValue;
  @pxValue: (@sizeValue * 10);
  font-size: ~"@{pxValue}px"; 
  font-size: ~"@{remValue}rem";
}`

Comment: Is your website hosted on more than one server?

Comment: I do see the toggling between big and small fonts. Looking at the dev tool (in Chrome), all static assets are unchanged (304), so the only thing that comes to mind is that some sort of conflict of CSS definitions in your site and the browser randomly picks one. I see that the computed values of CSS toggles the font sizes between 20px and 32px (font-size) and height between 70px and 105px.

Comment: @Kendra Please delete your comment, you should always add the code to your question. Somebody did already, but next time please do it yourself and leave a comment that you've done it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug in Chrome, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=319623

Meanwhile try using em instead of rem on the body tag or apply font-size to a wrapper element

```
body > div {
  font-size: 1.4rem
}
```

as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20173967/2459418

Comment: That's strange, I've never noticed it on another website.  Thanks for the info!