# Font size on my website grows then shrinks when I refresh or visit new page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

I'm working on updating my research lab website, and I'm using a Jekyll framework with Bootstrap. Whenever I navigate to a new page or refresh my current page, the font size grows slightly, then returns to its normal size. This makes for a jerky experience. My work in progress is currently on [rigglemanlab.github.io](https://rigglemanlab.github.io), and the page where this issue is most noticeable is [rigglemanlab.github.io/members](https://rigglemanlab.github.io/members/). The code for this site is on [github.com/benlindsay/lab_site](https://github.com/benlindsay/lab_site).

I've tried some answers to similar posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21952492/2680824) where the suggestion was to add the following to my css sheet:

```
body > div {
  font-size: 1.4rem
}
```

I tried variations of that like `em` instead of `rem` and `html` instead of `body > div` and setting the `@font-size-base` variable to `1.4em` or `1.4rem`, but the same behavior persisted with each attempt. How can I clean up the rendering of my website?

Comment: I see no issue on Chrome or Edge.  Which browser are you experiencing this with?

Comment: @James I'm seeing it on Chrome and Safari on my computer, but when I log into a remote Linux machine and use Firefox, I don't see it...does that mean it's a problem with my Macbook? I only see this problem on my website. Even the website whose framework I tweaked (bedford.io) doesn't have this problem on my computer.

Comment: @JamesKorden oops didn't tag you properly

Comment: It sounds platform specific.  This is going to be one of those where you need to recreate it and see if it's a "foible" of one particular OS/Browser, unfortunately.

Comment: @JamesKorden Yuck. One thing I noticed is if I do inspect element on any of the headers and look at the font-weight property, it gives the font weight of 500 from my style sheet, and underneath it says `bold   h1    user agent stylesheet` with `bold` crossed out. It does kind of look like my pages start with bold text, then it gets unbolded. Could that have something to do with it? I have no idea what `user agent stylesheet` means.

Comment: Never mind...I think I ruled that out. I replaced a `h1` tag with text in a div with an id and specified the font size and weight and I still saw the same problem even without having an overridden bold property.

Comment: I see what looks like a FOUF, but you're not using any webfonts, are you? Hm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mr Lister points out, it's probably a case of FOUT (flash of unstyled text), as it looks like you're using TypeKit.

A quick solution to this is to use TypeKit's built in events to hide text until the webfonts has loaded.

```
.wf-loading { visibility: hidden; } /* font is loading and hidden */
.wf-active, .wf-inactive { visibility: visible; } /* font has loaded and is visible */
```

Comment: ... which is generally being referred to as FOIT (flash of invisible text). I would choose FOUT over FOIT 90% of the time.

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. I took it a step further and removed everything related to typekit from my site. That was leftover from the original template I borrowed, and I don't think it was actually doing anything anyway since I don't have access to the kitId that's in there (I assume...).