# Why is this HTML form sometimes rendering differently just by reloading the page in the browser?

Tags: html, forms, firefox, browser, konqueror

The following valid HTML5 document renders randomly (font and box sizes change in an unpredictable manner) just by reloading it in the browser (make sure to do shift-reloads so the browser cache gets reset). I see no reason why this should occur. What's going on?

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Some title</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Some heading</h1>

<form id="myformid" action="myformaction.php" method="post">
    <label>label1: </label><input type="text" name="name1" required><br>
    <label>label2: </label><input type="text" name="name2"><br>
    <label>label3: </label><input type="text" name="name3"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>This is a test</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by differently? What's different?

Comment: Sounds like you have something weird going on with your browser.

Comment: No. I've tried it under multiple browsers and multiple operating systems. Less noticeable and less frequent on Windows Firefox 73 but still there. I ask that any further people commenting on this question at least try to duplicate the bug before replying.

Comment: I tried the below code. It works fine. Try to run my code.

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII: you should create a jsfiddle or a SO snippet, this may help us to "see" the behavior

Comment: I don't see why copying-n-pasting an html file is so hard but here's a jsfiddle.... https://jsfiddle.net/6dya52m7/   I was actually surprised that the issue appears in jsfiddle but it is harder to notice. If you keep hitting "Run", you will eventually see button renders differently (watch the corners... round vs square). I didn't get the font and input boxes to change with jsfiddle yet, only the browser directly.

Comment: I also cannot replicate your bug testing in multiple browsers and with network throttling. Can you provide a screen recording of what you're experiencing?

Comment: Make sure to do shift-reloads, otherwise you are just reviewing the same cached page over and over and you'll never see the issue. Regardless, the bug can be seen in the jsfiddle.

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue no matter what browser I am using, nor in JSFiddle. But to make sure this isn't an issue, you could always add styling: https://jsfiddle.net/Apolymoxic/L14gtfow/13/

Comment: Consider: verify you don't have any extension running like a password manager that is scanning input fields to see if they can be filled in.  These extensions sometimes modify the HTML.

Also consider making DOCTYPE upper-case.  Technically it is case insensitive, but different browsers may be picky.

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII : I runned 50 times your jsfiddle with cache disabled, I didn't see any changes (no rounded corners, nothing). Like Geoff Cox said, you might have some extensions activated. Did you try it on another setup to be sure it's not environnement related ?

Comment: I just tried running this a few times on chrome. no changes. might be better if you have video evidence because nobody seems to be able to replicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something specific to your current setup, and without more information it is really difficult to say exactly why it is happening...

That said there are some obvious reasons as to why it could be happening.

1. Extensions. It could be that you have an extension or plugin that is altering the page rendering. For example Greasemonkey customizes the way a web page displays or behaves, by using small bits of JavaScript.

To ascertain if this is the case, Start Firefox in Safe Mode. Safe Mode temporarily disables all extensions, uses the default theme, and turns off hardware acceleration. To do this; Click the menu button, click "Help" and select "Restart with Add-ons Disabled…" Firefox will start up with the Firefox Safe Mode dialog. If this fixes it then note it could be either an extension or hardware acceleration - to isolate which try step 3 below.

2. Zoom. It could be that you are inadvertently changing the zoom level of the browser thus causing the font and box sizes change.

To ascertain if this is the case reset the zoom level when you notice the change in rendering. Click the menu button on the right. The customization menu will open and you will see the zoom controls at the top. Make sure that zoom level is set to 100%

3. Hardware acceleration. With some GPUs and drivers, Firefox can have trouble showing text or objects on pages.

To ascertain if this is the case, you can try turning off hardware acceleration to see if it fixes the problem. Click the menu button and select "Preferences".
Select the "General" panel. Under "Performance", uncheck "Use recommended performance settings". Additional settings will be displayed. Uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available".

Other than that providing screen-shots of the issue would go a long way towards isolating the cause of the rendering issue you are seeing.

Comment: You seem to be right. I cannot duplicate the issue using Safe Mode with Firefox. I still see the issue using konquerer, which is odd because I don't use any extensions or anything for it.

Comment: In that case I would make sure that your graphics drivers are up to date - if you are seeing it across applications that would make the most sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

*document renders randomly (font and box sizes change in an unpredictable manner) just by reloading it in the browser*

Except for extensions on your browser messing with you, the only other thing that comes to my mind when you mentioned clearing the cache is that scripts/css file fails to load, or loads only partially on one of the reloads. That could make the HTML look differently. But I don't see any custom css even being used, so I'm pretty doubtful.

**Edit:**

Is it linked to this bug? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=319623

**Edit2:**

Do you by any chance have font-size set in rem's on a body tag, and are using chrome? This is the only similar issue I was able to find, and it deals with that specific thing, which is apparently a known Chrome bug.

[Chrome not respecting rem font size on body tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099844/chrome-not-respecting-rem-font-size-on-body-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the environment setup like below few details we would not be able to help much.

- Which OS => windows/linux/other with specific version
- Which browser => IE/Chrome/Firefox with specific version
- Any extension on browser/PC which making this behavior
- and there are many more points.

I just simply saved your html and run on IE and Chrome without noticing any single difference on every fresh reloads.

So more information is required to understand the problem.