# chrome font size is not calculated correctly (html rem)

Tags: html, css

html set font size 20px

the element set font size 1.4rem, but chrome render 38px font.  why not 28px?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaJM2.png

how to fix it?

[image]

body css

[image]

selected element

[image]

the element with class `.row1` is correct calculation

[image]

the difference between `.row1` and `.row2` is the display style

`.row1` is flex, `.row2` is block by default

online demo

http://qinshenxue.github.io/remdemo

demo screenshot

[image]

Comment: Probaly because somewhere in your `css` file the property is overwritten with a `!important` statement.

Comment: Please show us the css on `body`, please

Comment: What does "-webkit-font-size-delta" mean in your screenshot? I tried searching the web, but I only found dead ends.

Comment: @MaxiGui  body css in picture 2

Comment: OK So the answer is very simple. `rem` calculation can be based either on `html`either on `body`. In your case it means that your selected element on your first picture, is based on the body size which means 20px * 1.4rem = 28px. So if set a font-size of an element of your body with `rem` it will be calculated  from the `body` size. I guess

Comment: @MaxiGui But the OP's question is, why does it come out as 38 rather than 28.

Comment: @MrLister Sorry if I was not clear but on his 1st picture, he has a selected element (I dont know which). But the element is under the element body and if he applies for example 1.35rem on this selected element, it will calculate as follow: 28px * 1.35rem = 37.8px. so `body size * element size`

Comment: To be precised, the full calculation should be `(html size * body size) * element size` which should be around: `(20 *  1.4) * 1.4` so **37.8px**. But without the selected element, it is just supposition

Comment: the selected element  on 3rd picture

Comment: Ok then it is not that, please provide code or demo on jsfiddle / codepen to go more further

Comment: @qinshenxue.com After further research, it seems to be a specific bug from chrome. replacing the `rem` by `em` on the body should fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099844/chrome-not-respecting-rem-font-size-on-body-tag

Comment: This was closed as not suited to the site, but it should have been closed as a duplicate instead, since #20099844 has the answer.

Comment: @MaxiGui  demo  url http://qinshenxue.github.io/remdemo, 

demo screenshot on the fifth picture

Comment: @RossPresser  The question may be different from #20099844

Comment: @quinshenxue.com did you try to change rem to em in body as it says in the ticket? Or in my last comment? Did you check on other browser. And yes, I think it is duplicate

Comment: @MaxiGui  ok, thanks