# Chrome will increase the font size when zooming out

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have the following code :

CSS

```
#container{
    font-size: 0.625em;
}

#div1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

#div2 {
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">
    This is a test message.This is a test message.This is a test message.This is a test message.
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        This is a test message.This is a test message.This is a test message.This is a test message.
    </div>
</div>
```

Chrome Version

```
Version 35.0.1916.153 m
```

When you zoom to 50% or smaller in Chrome, the size of the two divs will become different.
If your check the font-size in dev tool, your will realize that 
 Chrome automatically increased the font-size of the document.

Can anybody tell me why this happens?
And how could I prevent it?

I am doing some research on the difference of em and px, so change the width of #div2 to 200px is not acceptable.

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/nigthadow/eVV4P/4/)

**Updated the content and source.**

Thank you for your help.

**Updated June 16th, 2014**

Found something interesting and wanna share with you guys here.

If you had ever touched the "Advanced font settings" in Chrome, or using an default version(not Chinese or Japanese):

1. you will never be allowed to set font-size to some number smaller than 6px(in Chinese or Japanese version it will be 12px).
2. 1em will never go smaller than 6px(12px), when you measure something like "height" with "em".
3. if you set a text to 6px, and zoom to 50%, you may expect to see the text rendered like 3px(become to half). But the text will be set to 12px by chrome, and may break your layout.

Thanks to Dawar Husain. He helps me realize the minimum font size thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See, you used px for the first div and em for the second.

**Chrome has a minimum font size and fonts smaller than it will be displayed as that font size only. (see your Chrome Settings)**

Now, using div with **px**, the box goes on and becomes even smaller on zooming at 33% (or 25% or 50%) but using **em**, the box remains the same size when the minimum font-size has been reached. see

[image]

**em** is useful on browsers which implement zooming by scaling the font size like Chrome. So if you size all your elements using em they scale accordingly.
**em** makes sure that the whole content is displayed as it is even if the size of **div** changes (on zooming). Hope you got your answer :)

### EDIT

In IE10, there's no minimum font size in settings as in GC35. So the **em** **px** render like each other.

Comment: ems are a really good unit, but can become confusing as they are relative to their parent. I'd recommend considering using rem instead (similar to em but relative to the root) with a px fallback for older browsers: http://andy-carter.com/blog/using-scalable-css-units-for-font-sizes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if you zoom the page to 50% and set the font-size of #div2 to 5px through dev tool, #div2 will become smaller, so I don't think it is the "minimum font size" problem.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja thank your for the advise. As you can see, I set container to "font-size: 0.625em ", which means 10px. And the two divs are direct children of the container, so their em should be 10px.

Comment: *div2* is not becoming smaller for me (even at 1px font size), although I have same version of Chrome as yours. here:[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AfEno). And for ems, use this conversion formula - `em = desired element pixel value / parent element font-size in pixels`

Comment: Thank you. After some research on advanced font settings, figured out it is the minimum font-size problem. But it is interesting that I can set font-size to some number smaller than minimum font size, and it works for text but not width with "em". Thank you again.

Comment: I am curious. How is it working for you but not me? I think the minimum font size in Chrome is 6px. I changed the first div's Font-size to be 1px but it is still showing as 6px. How is it showing size smaller than 6px for you? here: [IMAGE](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2z73mdh.jpg). Hey i updated your code and included a div3 with font size = 6px and set the font size of div2 to 1px. both divs are rendering exactly similarly. link:[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBzCh?editors=110)

Answer (score 1):

The divs has different width.

10em is not always equivalent to 100px

try setting the same width (em or px)

> An em is equal to the current font-size, for instance, if the
>   font-size of the document is 12pt, 1em is equal to 12pt
>
> One pixel is equal to one dot on the computer screen

refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) page for documentation

your updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eVV4P/3/)

```
body {
            font-size: 0.625em;
        }

        #div1 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: green;
        }

        #div2 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
        }
```

**update**

if it doesn't work try with this css property

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Comment: In this demo, I set font-size of body to 0.625em, which equals to 10px, so 10em will be 100px. I want to know what will happen to 'px' and 'em', during zoom-in and zoom-out, so I create this demo.

Comment: If you set it to 0 the fonts are invisible!!

Comment: Is there any problem with my answer? Doesn't it solve your question?

Comment: I set the width of div2 to 20em on purpose. And in this demo em should be 10px. I want to know what chrome has done when I zoom-in and zoom-out, and why chrome do that. So I cann't accept your answer, sorry.

Comment: "I set font-size of body to 0.625em, which equals to 10px, so 10em will be 100px." That only holds true if the default font size is 16px. When you set the font-size to 0.625em, that means 62.5% of some other value - specifically, some other font size. Depending on the font size of the thing outside container, 0.625em might be something very different than 10px.

Comment: "One pixel is equal to one dot on the computer screen." This is no longer true, and hasn't been for quite a long time.