# Rem-Based Layouts, Zooming on chrome is inconsistent, PX vs REM

Tags: css, google-chrome, web-standards

I've been wracking my brain over this one, google searches don't really have much in the way of help or even documentation of this problem but it's greatly affecting my current conversion to a mobile-friendly design.

Everywhere I go, everyone's touting using `rem`-based layouts as the new gold standard, and on the surface the virtues of this approach seem ideal (full accesibility support for both reference pixel based scaling and font-size scaling to support many DPIs and many screen sizes / settings).

However I've run into a rather large snag, I'm finding that Chrome (and possibly all webkit browsers but I don't have a mac atm to test) **don't seem to scale the same as the rest.**

With the initial setup like this:

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
body { font-size: 1.6rem; }
```

We should be able to set up all our measurements using 1/10th the pixel size in rems:

```
.my-element { height: 15rem; } /* 150px */
```

I've created a simple example that illustrates my problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/gLkpz88q/2/embedded/result/

When you use Chrome and you scale this way out, notice how the layout stops scaling but the content continues.

Compare this to Firefox, IE11, Edge and you don't see this behavior at all, they all scale uniformly and continually.

Here's (Top-Left: Chrome, Top-Right: IE11, Bottom-Left: Edge, Bottom-Right: FireFox) side-by-side:
[image: Example]

As you can see this has some terrible implications for layouts if the `rem` unit scales differently than everything else.

I'm not certain how to proceed with this scenario as it seems like WebKit/Chrome have decided to handle scaling completely differently and this calls in to question all the scaling scenarios going forward.

There's a number of articles advocating just using pixels as the **CSS Reference Pixel** takes care of mobile scaling rather well:

- [Just Use Pixels](https://benfrain.com/just-use-pixels/)
- [R.I.P. Rem, Viva CSS Reference Pixel!](https://mindtheshift.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/r-i-p-rem-viva-css-reference-pixel/)

However these tend to ignore the font-scaling issue, citing it as an unlikely situation.

I did a quick look around at man big mobile friendly/friendlyish sites I could think of from large & successful companies and it seems most of them just use pixels for all their layout needs. (Google, Facebook, Wordpress, Twitter, Bootstrap 3, [and to some extent Bootstrap 4], [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), and [WebPlatform](https://webplatform.github.io/))

Is Chrome the new Standards-Busting IE? Or am I doing something horribly wrong? I'm tempted to just use pixels at this point for consistency.

Comment: Thanks for posting a 300bounty question - I have never been more motivated to research something ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because Chrome's behavior of setting a minimum font-size, so if you zoom-out, chrome will set the minimum font-size to 6px (12px for chinese and japanese version). So your `div` will have a minimum width as it depends on your base font-size (which can't be smaller then chrome's minimum).

See also:

[Chrome will increase the font size when zooming out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200797/chrome-will-increase-the-font-size-when-zooming-out)

**[Edit]** Additional Information:

Chromium Tickets & Discussions On this topic:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16875
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36429

`-webkit-text-size-adjust` Support Dropped, so the viable solution for this behavior is not reliable anymore:

https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/145168/webkit

Comment: That's really interesting, and makes a lot of sense. I wish this information was easier to find out, I had no idea that chrome capped the min-size on the default font size. I understand the reasoning but it does produce some awkward results.

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to start my answer by addressing your closing statement first, purely because it caught my eye (besides the humongous bounty).

"*Is Chrome the new Standards-Busting IE? Or am I doing something horribly wrong? I'm tempted to just use pixels at this point for consistency.*"

Yes and no. I have more problems with things not working in WebKit browsers than I do in any other mainstream browser engine, but after investigating the individual issues, I generally find that it's because WebKit tends to stick to the rules provided by W3C more rigidly than others.

Most other browser engines seem to be very lenient with developers, and I love them for this, but we can't necessarily crucify WebKit for following the rules.

To extend the above statements into the rest of your question, I skimmed through [W3C document regarding relative font lengths](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20130730/#font-relative-lengths). Under the heading for **rem units** you will notice the first line stating:

> Equal to the computed value of ‘font-size’ on the root element.

Unfortunately, `font-size` in itself is relatively open to interpretation by your browser engine.

Cyrix's answer is correct in that Chrome will adjust your font size based on a *minimum font-size* that it has built in to the engine. To solve your problem easily, you could use the [text-size-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust?v=control) or the newer [font-size-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust) rule on your container element to prevent this:

```
* { /* Replacing "*" with ".my-element" would probably be better for the rest of your site*/
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-font-size-adjust: none;
}
```

The problem however is that older versions of Chrome don't accept font-size-adjust, and newer version only accept font-size-adjust **and only when experimental features** are enabled.

In closing, to answer the rest of your questions, `rem` and `em` is a wonderful unit of measurement if you are working with actual text content etc. Think in the lines of:

- If you want your`<h1>`'s to always be about 25% bigger than your body text `h1 { font-size: 1.25rem; }`
- If the height of your header bar must always be 3 times the height of the line of text inside it `.header { height: 3em; }`

If however you are working with a container type block that needs to fit a specified content block on the inside, it's always better to work with something more stable. Keep in mind, *stability* does not mean *unresponsive*.

Take this for example:

```
.my-element {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

This will float your element nicely in the middle of the page, whilst keeping the element at a size that fits the content inside it, and if the screen size decreases to a point smaller than your `.my-element` height, it will adjust accordingly.

## In short.

- Yes, Chrome breaks things on a scale that makes IE jealous, but that's ok.
- Yes, a lot of people do try to punt using relative font units as the best thing to do, however contrary to what they may say, you don't need to use it for everything.
- Your end result should be a responsive web page. Your means to achieving this will differ based on the content you have.
- Font scaling is a influencing factor that is most likely going to be around for a while, if you are worried about how it may affect your web page, ensure that only the elements that **need** to be scaled in relation to your font, will scale with your font.
- *"I'm tempted to just use pixels at this point for consistency."* This is the logical conclusion in most cases, so go for it :)

Comment: I tried to answer all of your questions, and address all of your comments, but feel free to let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer the question with research & detail. I had a real hard time with figuring out who to give this bounty to here because cryix's answer was pinpoint accurate as to what was going on, but much lower effort and not exactly authoritative. Ultimately his answer is what lead me to the authoritative information, and the greater understanding I was looking for.

Comment: I appreciate your motivation, and pointing out the `font-size-adjust` but that's not really a stable way of working with this problem as it's a draft, vendor specific, instable feature that's not actually designed for solving this problem (even if it does by accident). I hope this doesn't discourage you from answering questions or seeking bounties, I do appreciate the effort.

Comment: @Aren  Ah to be honest, I didn't really expect the bounty, purely because Citrix already had the correct answer, but I did enjoy the research so thought I'd post some more info here (gotta farm those up votes ;) ) thanks for responding with a comment though, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use this CSS `{ font-size: 62.5%; } body { font-size: 1.6rem; }` it causes more problems that it is worth, due to the fact that you will get different results on browsers that use different base font sizes. Just use this site to calculate the correct rem values. http://pxtoem.com/

This should give you consistent results.
https://jsfiddle.net/WizardCoder/gLkpz88q/3/

UPDATE
https://jsfiddle.net/WizardCoder/gLkpz88q/5/

Comment: I know of the distaste to the `62.5%` trick, but not doing it will still fall prey to different default font sizes on different browsers as well, the standard will just be "bigger". The fiddle you provided still shows the same base behavior between **33%** and **25%** zoom levels, the larger base size makes the problem more subtle but it doesn't prevent it outright. You will note that the general layout more or less stays the same between 33 and 25, but the image scales down meaning the relationship between it and the rem-based content around it doesn't stay consistent.

Comment: Actually it has the same issue. As cyrix states in his answer, this is just what chrome does. Why do you want to be able to zoom out that far anyway?

Comment: It's less about wanting to zoom out that far, and more about wanting to know why it's happening and if it'll burn me elsewhere later. Making a calculated risk assessment of this deviant behavior is important for justifying an approach to management for the longevity of a project.

Comment: Personally I this has never been an issue for any of my projects. Mostly because my builds are fully responsive with REM based media queries, so the website will adapt to any differences in font sizes between browsers. Someone may disagree though, that just my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue **non-uniform** browser **zoom in zoom out** on my project while setting the **base rem** . *I have used rem in most of the place in the project* .so,I had to set **base rem based on the screen size dynamically**. I will share few ways to set the base rem and issue I faced.The zoom in and zoom out inconsistent is caused because when we zoom out the screen width icreases and when we zoom in the the screen width decreases.So,if we set rem using the media queries or vw it will look inconistent while zooming in and out.

**Fixed unit** to set base rem like **px ,%**:

```
    html{
      font-size:68%;
           or
      font-size:16px;
    }
```

*pros*:

- same base rem on all the screen size.
- The browser zoom in zoom out will be consistent

*cons*:

- As it would be fixed value doesn't change based screen size.
- sometimes the elements can't adjust on small screen size becoz of the specified base rem

**Media queries** to set base rem:

```
html {
  font-size: 17px;
}
@media (max-width: 1536px) {
  html { font-size: 15px; }
}
@media (max-width: 1920px) {
  html { font-size: 13px; }
}
```

*pros*:

- The base rem changes based on screen size.

*cons*:

- The browser zoom in zoom out will be inconsistent

**vw** to set base rem:

```
    html{
      font-size:1vw;
    }
```

*pros*:

- the base rem will change based on the screen size and adjust. If zoom in zoom out is not important for you project.It would give perfect adaptation for the screen.

*cons*:

- The browser zoom in zoom out will be consistent but the zoom in zoom out won't be working on few elements.so,it might look messy sometimes

**Dynamic unit combination** to set base rem:

```css
html{
  font-size:calc(.5em+.5vw);
}
```

*pros*:

- Just need to adjust em and vw for base rem as we need for one screen.then base rem will change based on the screen size and adjust.
- the zoom in and zoom out will be consistent.