# My application uses rem values. How can I relate this to pixels?

Tags: css

My browser width is 1440px and I would like to make an element that's just a bit smaller than the width of the browser screen.  So just a bit smaller than 1440px.

Can someone explain to me the way pixels relate to rem?  How does my browser decide the number of pixels in a rem unit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799236/should-i-use-px-or-rem-value-units-in-my-css

Comment: Try `calc(100% - 10px)`

Comment: Pixels relate to `rem` in a manner that depends on the root element font size. This directly follows from the definition of `rem`. So it is unclear what you are really asking. To make an element a bit smaller than 1440px, set it to 1439px. If you set in `rem` units, it will always depend on the root element’s font size, which will always ultimately depend on the browser and its settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me the way pixels relate to rem? How does my
>   browser decide the number of pixels in a rem unit?

`rem` stands for *root-em* which is the font-size of the root element. In HTML the root element is `<html>`. UAs usually apply a `font-size` of `16px` to `html`, Therefore `1rem` would be equal to `16px` in that case.

> **[5.1.1. Font-relative lengths: the ‘em’, ‘ex’, ‘ch’, ‘rem’ units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths)**
>
> Aside from ‘rem’ (which refers to the font-size of the root element),
>   the font-relative lengths refer to the font metrics of the element on
>   which they are used [...]
>
> **`rem unit`**   Equal to the computed value of ‘font-size’ on the root element.
>
> When specified on the ‘font-size’ property of the root element, the
>   ‘rem’ units refer to the property's initial value.

And the *initial* value of `font-size` is `medium`.

Comment: Unless you've changed the default fonts in the browser's settings.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `%` instead? `rem`/`em` are units relative to the font size, not screen size.

In your case you may want to do:

```
width: 95%;
```

or

```
width: calc(100% - 10px);
```

depending on what exactly is your need.