# Convert from pixels to em

Tags: css, less, less-mixins, unit-conversion

I watched a really good tutorial about bombproof webdesign from Tutsplus the other day. The instructor had an awesome function that was made in Stylus.

```
$base_font_size = 16

$base_font_size_ems = unit($base_font_size / 16, em)

$px = unit(1 / $base_font_size, rem)

$px_em = unit(1 / $base_font_size, em)
```

To call this cool function in Stylus, you would just type:

```
.button
  font-size: 16 * $px
  border-radius: 3 * $px solid #000
```

If I understand this correct. The function lets me think in pixels but outputs everything in em.
Now, how do I do the same function in Less? :-)

Comment: Thank you for this! I needed it in stylus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conversion for that from Stylus to Less is fairly straight-forward. The equivalent Less code would be as follows:

```css
@base_font_size: 16;
@base_font_size_ems: unit(@base_font_size / 16, em);
@px: unit(1 / @base_font_size, rem);
@px_em: unit(1 / @base_font_size, em);

.button{
  font-size: 16 * @px;
  border-radius: 3 * @px solid #000;
}
```

---

Note that the above is just a direct conversion of your code in question and would currently always result in same value for both `em` and `rem`. However `em` and `rem` would generally be same only if the root font size and the parent's font size are the same. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799236/should-i-use-px-or-rem-value-units-in-my-css) for more information about `em` and `rem`.

The below snippet is a revised version where we have a separate mixin for doing the px to em/rem conversion. Here we set the root font size in a variable (global scope) and then we set the parent font size within each selector block (local scope) and is passed as an argument to the mixin. Based on these, the rem and em values are output as appropriate.

```css
@root_font_size: 32;

.rem_em_px_conversion(@parent_font_size: 32){

  @px_rem: unit(1 / @root_font_size, rem);
  @px_em: unit(1 / @parent_font_size, em);
}
.div{
    .rem_em_px_conversion();
    font-size: 16 * @px_em; /* change to 16 * @px_rem for converting to rem */
    border-radius: 4 * @px_em solid #000;
    .button{
      @parent_font_size: 16; /* this is same as parent div font size */
      .rem_em_px_conversion(@parent_font_size);
      font-size: 16 * @px_em;
      border-radius: 4 * @px_em solid #000;
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL! I don't have to tell you that I'm new to preprocessors... ;)

THANK YOU!

Comment: Always happy to help. I am also updating a revised version of the snippet to cover both px to em and px to rem conversion. Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the hollow tick mark (left side of the answer) when possible :)