# All margins and borders convert from px to %

Tags: html, css, border, margin

I am building an online shop for a project.

I have made all the element sizes `%` to keep the website fluid. However, all my margins and borders are in `px`, so when the browser is resized or people view on a different resolution screen, it really doesn't work.

I assume it's best that I convert to `%`, but it is a bit of a tedious task to do manually without a converter or the means for me to convert myself.

**How to people get around this? And do I actually want to convert to %?**

Comment: Use rem:
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/comprehensive-guide-when-to-use-em-vs-rem--cms-23984
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799236/should-i-use-px-or-rem-value-units-in-my-css

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using `rem`. It's much better and scales nicely. Depending on your browser support which you can check [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem)  I would argue it's the best alternative.

I'm not sure if you use [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) but it's another thing that I would consider using as you can create a [sass mixin](http://sass-lang.com/guide) to convert `px` to `rem` with a nice fallback to `px` for older browsers. Here's a [link](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2013/07/01/easy-peasy-rem-conversion-with-sass/).

It's down to personal preference but these are what I would choose.