# Any reason to use pixels anymore?

Tags: html, css

On new, responsive projects, is there any good reason to use pixels for production environment (besides in media queries) if there are responsive units such as rem (and in conjunction with 62,5% trick)?

Comment: Look at the answer explained by Nasir-T https://stackoverflow.com/a/45822666/4389566.

Comment: @RajThakkar Thank you, that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense. I use rem inside media queries and whenever i need a root based units (this is useful only if change the root font size). Then i use pixels when i need an absolute size.

Relative units are still useful. You don’t have to think that absolute units are “old”. They cover differents use cases.