# CSS: Using rem font sizes for responsive views

Tags: html, css

I have heard that `rem` font sizings work best for responsive views.  Since `rem` fonts are based off the html tag.  Is that just because there are less places to have to reference in a media query?  Essentially, you just change the `html` font-size in a media query and all your `rem` references are adjusted based off the new `html` font size?  ...or is that the entirely incorrect reason why people prefer to use them when making responsive views?

example:

```
html {
   font-size: 14px;
}

div {
   font-size: 1rem; // equal to 14px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    html {
       font-size: 12px;   // so now all `div` would be worth 12px but i don't 
                          // have to manually change `div` font-sizes now
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [html - Should I use px or rem value units in my CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799236/should-i-use-px-or-rem-value-units-in-my-css)